# How do I filter results from an NSFetchedResultsController based on a calculated property?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have an `NSManagedObject` called `WorkOrder` with a boolean property `isComplete` defined in a category for that class.

I use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch these from the data store and display them in a table view. I'd like to be able to filter the results based on the `isComplete` property, but of course the predicate in the `NSFetchedResultsController` can't do that because the property is not a Core Data attribute. I also can't filter the controller's `fetchedObjects` array because that property is read-only.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do without rolling my own data structure that mimics `NSFetchedResultsController` but allows me to filter the results post-fetch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments for Adam Eberbach's answer, I solved this using an `NSDictionary` (`self.workOrdersByDate`, below) to store the grouped results, as well as an `NSArray` (`self.dateSections`, below) to store the sorted keys of the dictionary.

```
// Fetch all the WorkOrders
NSArray *results = [WorkOrder findAll];

// Filter based on isComplete property
NSPredicate *filter;
if (self.segmentedStatus.selectedSegmentIndex == SegmentAssigned) {
    filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isComplete == 0"];
} else {
    filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isComplete == 1"];
}
results = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];

// Retain an NSArray of sorted NSDate keys
self.dateSections = [[results valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.scheduledStartDate.beginningOfDay"] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

// Create the dictionary
self.workOrdersByDate = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:self.dateSections.count];
for (int sectionNum = 0; sectionNum < self.dateSections.count; sectionNum++) {
    NSPredicate *sectionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scheduledStartDate.beginningOfDay == %@", [self.dateSections objectAtIndex:sectionNum]];
    NSArray *workOrdersForSection = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sectionPredicate];
    [resultsDict setObject:workOrdersForSection forKey:[self.dateSections objectAtIndex:sectionNum]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You receive an array of objects from the Core Data query, why not use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` on that result to get the array you really want?

In this case you can probably abandon using the NSFetchedResultsController to fill your table directly but it will still be useful for its delegate notifications when data changes.

Comment: Right I could do that, but then I lose all of the sorting and grouping that you get for free with `NSFetchedResultsController`. That may be my best option though.

Comment: Unless that boolean can be added to the NSManagedObject I don't know of a better way.

Comment: I ended up abandoning `NSFetchedResultsController` entirely and implementing this using an `NSDictionary` in order to preserve the grouping that `NSFetchedResultsController` gave me. I retain the sorted keys of the dictionary in a separate array.

Comment: @JamieForrest, that sounds like a complete answer... care to post it and self-accept? I'll throw some points on it.